# Run Model callback for particular Controllers

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I need to restrict few callbacks for particular controller. Which are

```
 before_create :transform_data_to_qb if File.basename($0) != 'rake' 
  before_update :update_data_to_qb unless File.basename($0) == 'rake'
  before_destroy :delete_data_to_qb unless File.basename($0) == 'rake'
```

How can I restrict these callback for a controllers in a way that they don't call for other controllers.

Comment: It seems liem you found a good example why the usage of callbacks are a bad idea in more complex apps.

Comment: @spickermann so far it seems so.